# C# WOW6432 registry node messin things up

Tags: c#, windows, winapi, registry

Trying to do the simple task of writing to the registry to make a C# application run at startup.

Using the basic `Win32.RegistryKey` setup but for some reason it keeps adding my keys into the `/SOFTWARE/WOW6432/Microsoft/Windows..` etc directory instead of plain ol `/SOFTWARE/Microsoft/Windows..`

Tried reading up on it a bit but there didn't seem to be a simple answer to this question:
How to I specifically write a key to the `/SOFTWARE/Microsoft/Windows` Registry Key instead of it writing to `WOW6432`? I've checked to make sure my Visual C# Express solution file had the platform listed as x86... so it's compiling correctly... I just don't want that `wow6432` directory.

Thanks for any advice!

Edit:

I'm now using the following and still no success:

```
Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey localKey32 = Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey.OpenBaseKey(Microsoft.Win32.RegistryHive.LocalMachine, Microsoft.Win32.RegistryView.Registry64);
```

Comment: Did you target the x64 platform?

Comment: IIRC it should be set to `Any CPU` and not `x86`

Comment: Platform target is not an available option in the Express edition afaik.  Editing the .vcproj by hand is possible.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your process targets x86 (i.e. it is a 32-bit process) and when run on a 64-bit machine under the WOW64 emulator, [registry redirection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa384232.aspx) comes into play. For certain parts of the registry the system maintains two distinct views, one for 32 bit processes and one for 64 bit processes. The list of keys affected by redirection is here: [Registry Keys Affected by WOW64](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa384253.aspx).

Redirection is transparent to an application. A 32 bit process access `HKLM\Software` and does not know (indeed does not need to know), that the 64 bit OS is actually accessing `HKLM\Software\Wow6432Node`.

You have a number of options available to you:

1. Switch to the AnyCPU target so that your process will run as either 32 bit or 64 bit depending on the underlying OS. This is awkward to achieve in the Express version because the target platform cannot be specified from the IDE.
2. Explicitly open a 64 bit view of the registry. In .net this requires the [`RegistryView`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.win32.registryview.aspx) enumeration. However, note that this functionality requires .net 4 and for earlier versions of .net, p/invoke is required to open views of the registry.
3. Continue to target x86 and write to `HKLM\Software`. A 64-bit system will read both views of the registry when processing the run at startup registry keys. In other words your existing approach already works!

As a final point I would comment that the task of setting up this registry key is best left to an installation program. Modify keys under `HKLM\Software` requires admin rights and typically you can only expect to have admin rights at install time.

Answer (score 3):

Try to explicitly open the registry in `64 bit` view by using `Registry64` in [RegistryView](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.win32.registryview.aspx). Similarly you can open `32 bit` view using `Registry32` option

According to MSDN

> You can specify a registry view when you use the OpenBaseKey and
>   OpenRemoteBaseKey(RegistryHive, String, RegistryView) methods, and the
>   FromHandle property on a RegistryKey object.

Comment: +1: Interesting. Haven't noticed that before. That said, it was only added in .NET 4.

Comment: Ooh, that _is_ a great option.

Comment: Well, you mean the 64 bit view rather than the 32 bit view.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your C# app platform is x64. Because `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node` is `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE` for `x86` apps in `x64` OS.

Comment: Then the app won't run on 32 bit system. AnyCPU is what's needed here.

Comment: `AnyCPU` is certainly an option - provided that it is going to eventaully resolve to `x64`. The OP will decide what he need, I cannot tell whether running always 64-bit is more important than being unable to run 32-bit.

Answer (score 0):

Not C# is to blame, but 64-bit Windows generally.

In Win64, registry values for 32-bit applications (i.e. compiled as x86) are stored under the Wow6432Node registry node, whereas registry values for 64-bit applications are stored directly under the given path.

See [Registry Redirector](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa384232%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724072%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), and [support KB](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/896459).