# Weird behaviour when reading registry in C#

Tags: c#, .net, registry

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [C# WOW6432 registry node messin things up](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8959983/c-sharp-wow6432-registry-node-messin-things-up)

This is the code:

```
var b1 = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey("software", true); 
var b2 = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey("software", true).OpenSubKey("company");
var r1 = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey("software").OpenSubKey("company").GetValueNames();
string resultString = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey("Software", true).CreateSubKey("company").GetValue(name).ToString();
```

I invoke it with `name` = `"ApplicationDirectory"`. At the last line, the first two variables point to the correct locations (based on their `Name` property). The problem is with `r1`, which doesn't list the contents of `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\company`, but rather `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\company`. Why is this? Is this some redirection in 64-bit machines?

Comment: Short answer: [Yes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa384232(v=vs.85).aspx).

Comment: 64bit computers have a section of registry separate to 32bit. I think it is called registry virtualisation.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8959983/c-sharp-wow6432-registry-node-messin-things-up/8960020#8960020

Comment: 63-bit machines? ;-)

Comment: @SamuelSlade: You know, when hardware degrades over time!

Comment: This question was asked yesterday...

Answer (score 2):

Yes, there is a redirection for 32-bit applications on 64-bit machines. See comments on your question, and also [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8960122/870604).

If you target .Net 4 or above, you'll be able to access both `Wow6432Node` (used for 32-bit applications) and "standard" node (the one used for 64-bit applications) as [RegistryKey.OpenBaseKey](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.win32.registrykey.openbasekey.aspx) method provides a parameter of type [RegistryView](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.win32.registryview.aspx) that allows choosing the correct node to use.

If you're using .Net 3.5 or previous version, then you'll have to use P/Invoke if you want to be able to read both 32/64 bit registry keys on a 64-bit machine. You'll have to use [RegOpenKeyEx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724897%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and specify `KEY_WOW64_32KEY` as flag for desired access. But this is another story and out of the scope of your question.