# Reading HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE in regedit and programatically doesn't show same keys

Tags: c#, registry, regedit

For reference, it is the `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\ORACLE` key. When I look into it, I see only 1 (inst_loc) subkey, and the two subkeys I added for the purposes of my application.

However, when the application (run under the same user account) reads it, it doesn't see the two keys I added, but sees a TON of other keys, like ORACLE_HOME, etc.

This finds a ton of keys, but not the two I added:

```
RegistryKey regkey = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey("SOFTWARE\\ORACLE", false);
foreach (string name in regkey.GetValueNames()) { }
```

Anyone have an idea about the cause of this discrepancy?

**EDIT**: I have done a bit of digging. It seems that when I load LocalMachine.OpenSubKey("SOFTWARE\ORACLE", I actually get HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\WOW6432NODE\ORACLE. But what if the value on the client machine is in HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\ORACLE? I must be able to somehow access this, preferably check for the value in both places...

Comment: What is your OS (x32 or x64)? Is the app x32 or x64?

Comment: Look in HKLM\Software\Wow6432Node\Oracle.  Project + Properties, Compile tab, Platform target matters.

Comment: OS is x64, application is x32. I guess I could compile the application as either, but the thing is, I need to be able to access both places from one application. I can't rely on the application that wrote the keys being the same type (32 or 64) as my application.

Comment: This was already answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8959983/c-sharp-wow6432-registry-node-messin-things-up

Comment: I found a very good [web page](http://www.rhyous.com/2011/01/24/how-read-the-64-bit-registry-from-a-32-bit-application-or-vice-versa/) on this in the answers to another stackoverflow question (it has code and links to related articles)